# Clone Windows User Settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

I have a windows 10 user and I need to create another user with the exact same permissions and setup. Is it possible to clone a windows user and their settings? I have the password to the original user and I am an admin user.

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure for cloning a user profile :

- Open *Control Panel > System*
- Click *Advanced system settings*
- Under *User Profiles* click *Settings ...*
- Click the profile to copy so as to select it
- Click the *Copy To ...* button
- Enter the name of, or browse to, the profile you want to overwrite.
  This will usually be in `C:\Users\username`.
- Click *Permitted to use*, and then add all user accounts to which you want to give full profile control.
- Click OK.

If the folder you copied from contained the files `ntuser.pol` and/or `ntuser.dat`,
verify that they were copied, and if not do it manually.
These are hidden system files and for viewing require in
File Explorer Options to disable `Hide protected operating system files`
and enabling `Show hidden file, folders, and drives`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed steps. On step 5 I am unable to click 'Copy to' though? If I select any user, the 'Copy To' button is always grayed out. I can select 'Default Profile' and it has 'Copy to' enabled but all others result in a grayed out button. Maybe because they are admins?

Comment: This won't clone permissions. Since each user has a unique SID it's not possible to clone them.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the profile you are using? It might be disallowed because some files are in use.