# Clone user in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, user-profiles

I am using Windows 11 Home version 22H2 and am wanting to clone a user account with the exact same permissions and setup. Both users are administrators.

I have followed the steps in this post: [Clone Windows User Settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1364764/clone-windows-user-settings) but I am not seeing the other user in User Profiles settings. The user is logged out.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just create a new user. A user by default will have identical permissions to that of another user unless they are an Administrator